# The function $f$ has property: $f(x)+f(1/x)=x$ and what is the largest set of real numbers?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functional-equations

**Problem.** $f(x)+f\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)=x$ and we need to figure out the largest set of real numbers that can be the domain of $f$.

**My steps:**

*Step 1.*
I substituted $x$ with $1/x$ to replace the reciprocal signs as shown below:
$f(1/x)+f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$
that's where I got stuck.

Comment: You should obtain $f\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)+f(x)=\dfrac 1x$ and thus...

Comment: The answer may depend on the formulation that has been left somewhat vague: a) "The function $f\colon D\to\Bbb R$ has the property that for all $x$ with $x\in D$ and $\frac 1x\in D$, we have $f(x)+f(1/x)=x$" or b) "The function $f\colon D\to\Bbb R$ has the property that for all $x$ with $x\in D$, we have $\frac 1x\in D$ and $f(x)+f(1/x)=x$"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$f(x)+f\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)=x\tag{1}$$

Replacing $x$ with $\dfrac{1}{x}$, we get
$$f\left(\dfrac{1}{x}\right)+f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x}\tag{2}$$

From $(1)$ and $(2)$, we get

$$x=\dfrac{1}{x} \Rightarrow x=\pm 1$$

Comment: And $f(x)=\tfrac{x}{2}$ satisfies the functional equation on this domain.

Comment: @Servaes Thanks. I was waiting for the OP's comment.